# how to call service from controller in grails

Tags: grails, service, dependency-injection, controller

I have a service class and i am trying to call the method of the service  in my controller as below.

```
class LogListController {

def ListLogDetails = { 
    println "We are inside List log Details-->"+params
    def logListHelperService
    logListHelperService.getFilePath(params)
}}
```

**Exception Message: Cannot invoke method getFilePath() on null object**

what is my mistake there..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def logListHelperService
```

must be declared outside of the ListLogDetails definition

```
def logListHelperService
def ListLogDetails = { 
    println "We are inside List log Details-->"+params
    logListHelperService.getFilePath(params)
}
```

should work