# How to call Service in Grails with groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I have one service in that i have a method to call and how can i acces this service.
I have seen sms plugin and installed it and How can i send sms from my application to the different mobiles.I followed the grails sms plugin but i didn't get any results ecxept ecxeptions

```
class SipgateService {

  static transactional = true

  def serviceMethod() {
    def sipgateService
    //def phoneNumber = 'XXXXXXXXXX' //phoneNumber according to E.164 specification
    //working alternative: 
    println "service"
    def phoneNumber = 'XXXXXXXXXX' 
    def result = sipgateService.sendSMS(phoneNumber, 'This is my Text to send!')
    result ?  'Sending Successful':'Sending failed'
    println "after service"

  }
}
```

Please explain me with an example.
thanks alot in advance.

Comment: dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250914/how-to-call-service-from-controller-in-grails ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call the plugin from a service method, you would need to do:

1. change the name of your service (so it isn't called `SipgateService`)
2. Add the `def sipgateService` as a class definition, not a method one

Does this work?

```
class MySMSService {
  static transactional = true

  def sipgateService // This will be injected from the SMS plugin

  def serviceMethod() {
    println "service"
    def phoneNumber = 'XXXXXXXXXX' 
    def result = sipgateService.sendSMS(phoneNumber, 'This is my Text to send!')
    result ?  'Sending Successful':'Sending failed'
    println "after service"
  }
}
```

Then, from a controller, define the link to `MySMSService` at class level, and call your `serviceMethod` method ie:

```
class MyController {
  def mySMSService  // this will be injected from your service

  // then, when you want to use it (from an action)

  def someAction = {
    ...
    mySMSService.serviceMethod()
    ...
  }
}
```