# When i used SMS plugin in grails i am getting error

Tags: grails, service, groovy

i have service to send sms to the mobile through Application. I am getting the follwing error.

2011-06-06 19:37:35,729 [http-8080-2] ERROR sipgate.SipgateService  - Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://samurai.sipgate.net/RPC2

Answer (score 0):

This probably means you are using an invalid username or password

Have you set up the config as explained on [the plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/sipgate) (at the top of the documentation)?

---

I also assume that this means your [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6251912/6509) was solved...  Can you accept the answer if my answer helped, or explain what you did to fix it if it did not?

Comment: yes, I set up user and pwd in conf/Config.groovy and phoneNumber in plugin provided service as it is in []the pluing page . and i accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim. You can only log in, if your Sipgate-Registration was verified by Sipgate.

Points, which you can check to see if your account is not working:

- Try to log in on the sipgate.de webpage
- Use the Perl-Client given here: http://www.sipgate.de/basic/api
  The client can be downloaded at this location:http://www.sipgate.de/beta/public/static/downloads/basic/api/sipgate_api_perl_examples.zip

Hopefully you should not be able to do at least one of these things. Then you know you have to talk to the support @ sipgate

The documentation on the plugin-page says, you have to have a 'conf/Config.groovy'-file. This means that you should have the basic Config.groovy file in the folder 'grails-app/conf/', which ships with every Grails installation. So my guess is that you might have created a different Config.groovy-file. So better check on the Config.groovy-file. The SMS-plugin should have generated some placeholders for you, where you need to enter your sipgate-account-data.